# Eclipse: Help with EGit

Tags: git, eclipse

I want to be able to use a version control system. Although Eclipse comes with CVS, I think it's better that I use a distributed version control system, such as *GIT*. I was pretty much sold after reading [this](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/Git_For_Eclipse_Users) article.

Anyway, I installed EGit and followed [this](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Basic_Tutorial:_Adding_a_project_to_version_control) guide on how to set it up. However, I ran in to a few problems:

- Adding .*project* and *.classpath* inside *.gitignore* did not seem to work.
- When I try to open a committed file, it throws an error, saying: "IO error reading Git blob [...]"

What am I doing wrong? If more information is needed, please specify and I will give.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure, but if EGit actually version `.project` and `.classpath`, adding them *after* in `.gitignore` won't work.
You need to [`git rm --cache` those two files first](http://help.github.com/git-ignore/). (through command-line).

Comment: I actually don't know how to access git through the command-line :/. Where would I find git after installing EGit?

Comment: @someguy: good question. I usually just unzip a msysgit (on Windows) to have command line version of the tool.

Comment: If I did that, it wouldn't be sync'd with Eclipse/EGit, would it?

Comment: Also, thanks for link. I think it was helpful. I guess I just have to untrack the files and track them again. However, I can't really test it since I've committed and I don't think I can remove them. OoT, but is it possible to delete commits?

Comment: @someguy: a/ It should be in sync with Egit (with an occasional project refresh). b/ Deleting commit is possible (but should be made with caution especially if you have already pushed your branch), essentially by resetting the HEAD to a previous SHA1 commit.

Answer (score 0):

EGit doesn't install c git, instead it relies on the Java implementation of git which is JGit.
If you want c git download it from http://git-scm.com/

--
Matthias